# How do I configure CartThrob to use billing address as shipping address by default?

Tags: cartthrob, shipping, authorize.net

A client sells digital products where the shipping address isn't even necessary but I guess Authorize.net sometimes declines payments because the default shipping address, which is never shown or even hidden in the form, does not match the billing address. Is there a way that I can set CartThrob to just always submit the billing address as the shipping address for digital products?

OR is there a way to completely disable shipping from being submitted to Authorize.net (or any payment gateway for that matter)?

The site is running CartThrob 2.61.

Comment: I know you can use the checkbox method (https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/checkout_form/#use_billing_info) or you could auto populate the hidden shipping fields with the billing data before submission. Someone from Vector might have a better solution though.

Answer (score 0):

If Authorize.net is requiring the billing info, then it would probably be easiest to set the fields during checkout.

You can use the cartthrob checkbox method - which is simply a jQuery based copy (setting values of fields via other fields) of the billing fields to shipping fields when checked.

A second method would be to use a scripted function on the form submit button to copy field values to hidden fields and then send the form.

Finally, you could directly edit the gateway and set the necessary values there prior to the data CURL to your gateway server. It would be a simple matter of copying variables prior to setting the charge data array.

You may be able to set your gateway's required fields or set what is being verified prior to charging the card, but that is something that you'll have to check directly with Authorize.net and see what info they are requiring that you submit.